# Recursively Create Binary Tree at Specific Depth

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I want to create a binary tree with a specific depth.
My code so far creates binary trees till a specific maximum depth, but also creates trees with lower maximum depths. I will illustrate my problem below.

My code so far (Method is called `create`):

```
public class BT<E>{
   E value;
   BT<E> left, right;

   public BT(E value)
   {
      this.value=value;
   }   

   public BT (E value, BT left, BT right) 
   {
      this.value = value;
      this.left = left;
      this.right = right;
   }

   private static final String[] random = {"a","b","c","d"};
   public static BT create(int depth) {
      if (depth > 1 && random.nextBoolean())//if not at the maximum depth
      //choose randomly a,b,c,d - nextBoolean ensures it is not balanced all the time
      {
         String random = OPERATORS[random.nextInt(OPERATORS.length)];
         return new BT(operator, create(depth-1), create(depth-1));//recursively create tree
      } 
      else {//when node is a leaf node, make it X
         String t = "x";
         return new BT(t);
      }
   }
}
```

The problem:
If I input 3 as the depth it should create trees like this **ONLY**:

```
    (c)              (d)         (a)
 (b)   (a)         (b)        (d)   (c)
(x)(x)(x)(x)     (x)  (x)             (x)
```

My code currently creates the trees as above but also includes trees like:

```
(x)       (c)           (d)
             (x)      (x) (x)
```

Clearly these aren't of depth 3. I do not want this. I **only** want the former without these exceptions.

Could somebody have a look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong and how to correct it.

Comment: Your definition of depth is inconsistent with the way that I have seen it defined.  Depth is the maximum length (or number of edges) from root to a leaf.  The trees that you say should be displayed when depth = 3 actually have a depth of 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the easiest approach would be to create a wrapper function which calls your create tree function.

The function will create a random free using your function, test to see if it has the needed length of depth X. If it is, it will return; if not, it will call your function again until it finds a tree with correct depth

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

> `random.nextBoolean()`

in this line:

```
if (depth > 1 && random.nextBoolean())
```

You're intending to create unbalanced trees with this statement, but this also has a very high chance of creating trees without any maximum depth branches. All you need is for **false** to be returned a few times in a row early on in the recursion and you have your undesired result. Given that there's a 50% chance for this to occur it will happen more than you think! To *guarantee* at least one branch with maximum depth you need a little more processing.

One suggestion could be to pre-determine one or more branches in your tree that will reach maximum depth, and leave the others to chance. As you're using a binary tree this can be done with booleans:

```
int depth = 3;
boolean[] branch = new boolean[depth];
for (int i = 0; i < branch.length; i++) {
  branch[i] = random.nextBoolean();
}
```

Once you have this, generate your tree as you're doing now. Once complete, move through your tree as the boolean[] dictates, using true for left and false for right. If you find that the child is missing for a particular boolean, and you haven't hit maximum depth, create that child and continue. This isn't a particularly attractive way of doing it, but it's cheap and fast.

Once this is working you can add more complexity - more guaranteed branches, and additional branches coming from those - in order to flesh out the tree. As your maximum depth increases it might be wise to lower the chance of ending a branch, as otherwise you'll end up with one long maximum depth branch and loads of smaller ones.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned the problem is in this line:

```
if (depth > 1 && random.nextBoolean())
```

What you have to do is:

- Control the evaluation order:

  Consider `return new BT(operator, create(depth-1), create(depth-1));`

  The left tree will always be evaluated first and then the right tree.
- Let the trees create leafs, if one of them has reached the desired depth:

  I created a boolean variable `finished` for this purpose

So first we will create a path with the desired depth. Then we will let the other paths either create a Tree or a Leaf.

```
    private boolean finished;

    public BT<E> create(int depth){
        if(depth<=0) { // One tree is at desired depth
            finished = true;
            return new BT<E>(null);
        }
        if(finished) // Let the other trees set a Leaf.
            if(random.nextBoolean())
                return new BT<E>(null);

        BT<E> temp = create(depth-1); // Control evaluation
        if (random.nextBoolean()) // evaluate left and right evenly distributed
            return new BT<E>(null, temp, create(depth-1));
        else return new BT<E>(null, create(depth-1), temp);
```

Note that the created tree will rather be sparse than dense, because of

```
if(finished)
    if(random.nextBoolean())
        return new BT<E>(null);
```

You might want to make the random variable depend on the number of current paths.